# TImer удаление через заданное время

Tags: android, время

есть ListView

```
listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    dataModels= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        dataModels.add(new DataModel(String.valueOf(i), "Android 1.0", "1", "September 23, 2008"));
    }
    adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Как реализовать ,чтобы через 4 секунды например удалилась 3 позиция  dataModels.remove(4);

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен `Handler`

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

//используем
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        dataModels.remove(4);
    }
}, 4000);//4000 это 4 секунды
```

Comment: после вашего кода я написал     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();но список не обновился и 4 позиция не удалилась , что я делаю не так?

Comment: попробуйте удалить Looper.getMainLooper()

Comment: ничего не поменялось

Comment: смотрите логи, может `Exception` какой ловит?

Comment: все что там выводит                                                                                
 12-09 17:09:39.321 11259-11259/? E/Zygote: v2
12-09 17:09:39.321 11259-11259/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
12-09 17:09:40.741 11259-11259/com.journaldev.customlistview E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = null
12-09 17:09:40.741 11259-11259/com.journaldev.customlistview E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@d448fc5

Comment: тогда смотрите ваш код внимательнее, ибо Handler это очень простое решение, которое работает везде.